# This question gave me a solution but now I have another issues

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I wanted to make useful an old Dell c600: started this question: [Install lubuntu 12.04 on an old Dell c600 : Video issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117510/install-lubuntu-12-04-on-an-old-dell-c600-video-issues)

It fixes the issues with my video with the puppy idea, but now I'm trying to get to work a modem 3g. That is a another issue I know but it works on my Ubuntu installation.

What I do with this?

Answer (score 2):

I sympathise with your issues but the answer to the meta question is quite simple:

- Either get it working with Ubuntu here, or
- If you use Puppy, you'll need to go to http://unix.stackexchange.com or another site that supports Puppy Linux for support on the modem. That sort of question would be off-topic here.

Comment: ok.will go to puppy then. sorry about that =D U can delete the question then,